# Loading Class from Path

Tags: java, urlclassloader, dynamic-class-loaders

I want to create 'modules' which extend a 'Module' interface, these would be separate jars that get loaded on runtime - essentially adding extra features. I want to have these loaded as the 'Module' object (from the interface).

I've tried the below code, and while my code prints out the `Found module`, it doesn't do anything after that.

```java
            try {
                Collection<URL> urlList = new ArrayList<>();

                Path pluginsDir = Paths.get(Common.getPlugin().getDataFolder().getPath(), "modules");

                try (DirectoryStream<Path> jars = Files.newDirectoryStream(pluginsDir, "*.jar")) {
                    for (Path jar : jars) {
                        System.out.println("Found module (" + jar.toFile().getName() + ").");
                        urlList.add(jar.toUri().toURL());
                    }
                }


                URL[] urls = urlList.toArray(new URL[0]);

                ClassLoader pluginClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls, this.getClass().getClassLoader());

                ServiceLoader<Module> loader = ServiceLoader.load(Module.class, pluginClassLoader);

                for (Module module : loader) {
                    System.out.println("module.getName() = " + module.getName());
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I'd expect it to print out the modules name (as an interface method) but it doesn't loop.

For example, a module would do;

```java
public class ExampleModule implements Module {
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Example";
    }

    @Override
    public void load() {
        Bukkit.getLogger().info("Hello!");
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the javadoc of ServiceLoader to understand how it works? Because there's nothing in your question that suggests you've configured the correct files.

Comment: I've had some research @JBNizet but I'm new to classloaders, so hoping to get some guidance.

Comment: I have read it yes, and I have META-INF inside my jar @JBNizet

Comment: A META-INF directory is not sufficient. What do you precisely have configured in your jar file to make the ServiceLoader? Post the relevant information.

Comment: Is this ok? https://hastebin.com/ayelabezek.xml

Comment: That's a section of a Maven pom file. It has absolutely nothing to do with a ServiceLoader. Again, read the javadoc. It says: *A service provider is identified by placing a provider-configuration file in the resource directory META-INF/services. The file's name is the fully-qualified binary name of the service's type. The file contains a list of fully-qualified binary names of concrete provider classes, one per line*. So. Do you have such a file?

Comment: You're very hostile.. I thought this could be automatically generated with maven? As maven-jar-plugin automatically does my META-INF stuff.

Comment: I have read it yes, though as I said -  I thought I could tell maven by service class and it would generate it